# SSRS plot value of DataSet multiple times

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, charts, ssrs-2016

I have a table of data like so.

[image]

I would like to plot it on the same graph. I managed to get it to plot when putting it in a table that sorts on category "GreenTemp1", but what I would like is to plot it together on the same chart. Can anyone help me?

Edit:
I would like it to plot it like this but it does not show anything.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add a separate series for each of the DeviceNames. The value expression for each series can be along the lines of:

```
=iif(Fields!DeviceName.Value = "GreenTemp1", sum(Fields!Value.Value), Nothing)
```

Obviously change the number for each series. Give each series its own legend name as well, and remove the category group for DeviceName.